# Set-ADUser based on Email in CSV File

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am trying to read information from a csv file that and use it to add phone numbers to our active directory if the email address is found in the csv file. (I know the EmailAddress attribute is not realiable, but it's all I have to work with based on where this data is being exported from).  I have a powershell script of:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$csv = Import-Csv c:\users\user1\Desktop\userphones2.csv
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $line.email} | 
    Set-ADUser -OfficePhone $line.phone
}
```

When I run this, for each record in the data file I get an error of

> Get-ADUser : Property 'email' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'

CSV file is structured this way:

```
#TYPE System.Data.DataRow
"email","phone"
"user@example.com","8885555555"
"user2@example.com","8885555552"
```

If I do a Write-Output in the foreach loop instead of trying to get the data, this works.  I have found many different syntaxes describing how to put a variable in a line like this for these filters, but nothing has worked.  How do I get this filter to work?

Comment: The CSV doesn't seem to have a field `email`. Please provide sample input data.

Comment: It does.  Write-Outputs work with the same variables.  I have included the first few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong name for the email property in AD.  It's `mail` not `EmailAddress`. I tested this in PowerShell and it works for me.

Also you can't use `$line.email` in a filter PowerShell doesn't know how to handle it.  I dont know the technical reason for this but I have never got it to work that way so I always put it in a variable.  Try this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$csv = Import-Csv c:\users\user\Desktop\userphones2.csv
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    $email = $line.email
    Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -eq $email} | 
        Set-ADUser -OfficePhone $line.phone
}
```

Comment: Comparing against `EmailAddress` works just fine. The problem occurs because the property can't be accessed inside the filter scriptblock.

Comment: So I have to use the mail property instead of EmailAddress within the scriptblock?  That seemed to work.  Thanks guys.

Comment: As Ansgar said it should work either way.  What the issue is is that you cant reference the csv value in the filter so you have to put it in a variable before you check it in the filter.  Did that solve your issue?